# Proof by Induction of Modified Boole’s Inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that $A_1, . . . , A_k$ is a collection of $k ≥ 2$ sets. Show that (using induction),

$$\big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}A_i \big| \ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} \big|A_i| - \sum\limits_{\{i,j\}} \big|A_i \cap A_j \big| $$

where the second term on the right sums over all subsets of [k] of size 2.

I must prove this by induction.

Take the base case $k = 2$,

$$ LHS = |A_1| + |A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_2|$$

$$RHS = |A_1| + |A_2| - 2|A_1 \cap A_2|$$

$$\implies LHS > RHS$$

So the base case $k=2$ holds!

Now consider $k$ true.

Take $k+1$,

$$\big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i \big| \ge \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} \big|A_i| - \sum\limits_{\{i,j\}} \big|A_i \cap A_j \big| $$

Now, I know the LHS can be written as,

$$\big| \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i \big| = \sum_{0 \neq I \subseteq [k+1]}(-1)^{|I| + 1} \big| \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i \big|$$

However, I'm stuck trying to play around with both the LHS and RHS to make the inequality hold for $k+1$. Could someone please offer a trick I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument for the base case isn’t quite right: the sum $\sum_{\{i,j\}}|A_i\cap A_j|$ is taken over all $2$-element subsets of $[k]$, **not** over all ordered pairs of elements of $[k]$, or even all ordered pairs of distinct elements of $[k]$. Thus, for $k=2$ the righthand side is $|A_1|+|A_2|-|A_1\cap A_2|$, not $|A_1|+|A_2|-2|A_1\cap A_2|$: you don’t count the pair $\{1,2\}$ twice. The base case holds because the lefthand and righthand sides are equal, not because the lefthand side is greater than the righthand side.

A small point about correct usage: it makes no sense to say that you’re assuming that $k$ is true, because $k$ is not a statement and therefore is not even the **kind** of thing that can be true or false. What you mean is that you are assuming that the inequality in question holds for $k$.

As for the induction step itself, going back to the inclusion-exclusion formula is unnecessary: this is a result that would actually be appropriate as part of the preparation for the inclusion-exclusion principle. What you can do instead is temporarily amalgamate $A_k$ and $A_{k+1}$ into a single set; then

$$\begin{align*}
\left\vert\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i\right\vert&=\left\vert\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right)\cup(A_k\cup A_{k+1})\right\vert\\
&\overset{(1)}\ge\left\vert\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1}A_i\right)\right\vert+\vert A_k\cup A_{k+1}\vert\\
&\overset{(2)}\ge\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}|A_i|+|A_k\cup A_{k+1}|\\
&\overset{(1)}\ge\sum_{k=1}^{k+1}|A_i|\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the inequalities $(1)$ follow from the base case, and the inequality $(2)$ follows from the induction hypothesis.

**Added:** I’m going to leave that as an illustration of how easy it is inadvertently to make something a little harder than necessary. In fact we could just observe that

$$\begin{align*}
\left\vert\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i\right\vert&=\left\vert\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right)\cup A_{k+1}\right\vert\\
&\overset{(1)}\ge\left\vert\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right)\right\vert+\vert A_{k+1}\vert\\
&\overset{(2)}\ge\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}|A_i|\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Very nice sir! Thank sir!